# Opencv java - Load image to GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, opencv

I'm developing an application using Java Opencv-2.4.4 and swing GUI. Problem is that I'm unable to find any solution, that shows efficient way how to print processed image (saved in *Mat* object) to java swing GUI. For this moment I'm using this clumsy solution:

```
javax.swing.JLabel outputImage;
outputImage.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/home/username/Output.png"));

private void sliderStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) { 
       .
       .
  Mat canny; // Here is saved what I want to plot
  String filename = "/home/username/Output.png";
  Highgui.imwrite(filename, canny);  // write to disk
  outputImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(filename)))); //update Icon
       .
       .
}
```

When user changes some values, inputs etc ., in GUI I have to overwrite *Output.png* on disk and update jLabel with new image from disk.

Is there any more elegant / efficient solution to this ? Is it posible to plot or convert *Mat* object directly to *Canvas* or *Image* or anything that is printable as image in swing ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jpeg encoding is interesting, but there are a couple problems:

- it is not a lossless format, you will lose image data when compressing
- it takes quite a while (around 6 to 10 times longer than the suggested one below)

> ```
> public Image toBufferedImage(Mat m){
>       int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
>       if ( m.channels() > 1 ) {
>           type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
>       }
>       int bufferSize = m.channels()*m.cols()*m.rows();
>       byte [] b = new byte[bufferSize];
>       m.get(0,0,b); // get all the pixels
>       BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(),m.rows(), type);
>       final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
>       System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);  
>       return image;
>
>   }
> ```

Comment: just one note: in imencode() function you can set ".png" as well. It depends of programmer needs, so there is no loss of information

Comment: I see. The problem is that it takes too long. The above procedure is close to the fastest possible. I believe that only pointing to native memory would be faster.

Comment: The solution that I've proposed will load image to GUI fast enough, but anyway, I found your answer very helpful. I use this technique(transform Mat into BufferedImage) when first processing image in OpenCV and than in ImageJ and doing it with thousands of images. And here the speed is really matters

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521848/opencv-template-matching-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-mat-data-ty)Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mat data type is not compatible: 5
 at org.opencv.core.Mat.get(Mat.java:1015)
 at util.Highgui.toBufferedImage(Highgui.java:94)
 at util.Highgui.imshow(Highgui.java:50)
 at Histogram_Matching.MatchTemplateDemoOperationsRun.MatchingMethod(MatchTemplateDemo.java:103)
 at Histogram_Matching.MatchTemplateDemoOperationsRun.run(MatchTemplateDemo.java:61)
...

Answer (score 15):

Yes there is more elegant way to do it. You can concert Mat to BufferedImage type and then just Load it with swing. The code to convert it to Buffered image is:

```
    Mat image_tmp = your image

    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();

    Highgui.imencode(".jpg", image_tmp, matOfByte); 

    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
    BufferedImage bufImage = null;

    try {

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And then you just can paint it in your GUI object:

```
g.drawImage(bufImage , 0, 0, null);
```

where g is of type Graphics

Hope this helps.

Comment: On OpenCV 3.X, Highgui is now replaced by Imgcodecs. The proper line is now Imgcodecs.imencode

Answer (score 2):

This is a readymade solution for `Imshow()` equivalent in Java OpenCV Its simple to use. API will look like:

```
Imshow im = new Imshow("Title");
im.showImage(matimage);
```

Visit here https://github.com/master-atul/ImShow-Java-OpenCV

This is a better solution as you don't store the image into disk and read again. Hence it reduces the overhead of reading from  a disk and thus is faster.

Comment: Hi MMD, I like the idea of wrapping up every Swing GUI to make a more concise Imshow class. I just think you should use my approach in the showImage(Mat img) method, because it's around 5 times faster. Thanks for the class =)

Answer (score 0):

Using @andriy's anwser. I came up with this solution. I used JFrame instead of Graphics. Hope this helps.

```
public void imshow(Mat src){
    BufferedImage bufImage = null;
    try {
        MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
        Highgui.imencode(".jpg", src, matOfByte); 
        byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufImage)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```