# Equivalent method for imshow in opencv Java build

Tags: java, opencv

sorry if I am asking a silly question, I am trying to learn openCV using Java build. In opencv samples i found there is method imshow in c++ or showImage in python, but i search in opencv Java API, i cannot found imshow method.

What is the equal method of imshow() and waitKey() in opencv with Java build?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no Java highgui wrapper yet ([link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/8119/how-to-display-image-on-java-release/)). You should use swing or swt to show image. See: [Opencv java - Load image to GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670933/opencv-java-load-image-to-gui)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, how about the waitKey method? is that same with thread.sleep?

Comment: i see, ermm, one more thing, do you know how to start a webcam and gain access to the live feed from it. i mean, so far i manage to capture my face through a webcam and detect it, now what i want to do is open my webcamera and detect my face without capturing it, it is something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTk_UwAYzVk

Answer (score 29):

```
public static void showResult(Mat img) {
    Imgproc.resize(img, img, new Size(640, 480));
    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
    Highgui.imencode(".jpg", img, matOfByte);
    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
    BufferedImage bufImage = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufImage)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no more `HighGUI` module in Java for 3.0 anymore use `Imgcodecs` insead

Answer (score 7):

This is a readymade solution for Imshow() equivalent in Java OpenCV
Its simple to use .
API will look like:

Imshow im = new Imshow("Title");

im.showImage(matimage);

Visit here 
https://github.com/master-atul/ImShow-Java-OpenCV

Answer (score 3):

I made something with swing and awt.

First, get `BufferedImage` from Mat img by `imencode` and `ImageIo.read`

```
        MatOfByte mMatOfByte = new MatOfByte()
        imencode(".png", img, mMatOfByte);
        byte[] byteArray = mMatOfByte.toArray();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        BufferedImage srcImage = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Second, change it to target size width and height (w,h) and use Rendering Hint to get clean image in expanding or reducing case.

```
            bufImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, srcImage.getType());
            Graphics2D g = bufImage.createGraphics();
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g.drawImage(srcImage, 0,0, w, h, 0, 0, srcImage.getWidth(), srcImage.getHeight(), null);
```

I used the target `bufImage` in JPanel's `paintComponent()` method.

For `waitKey()`, I used `KeyEventDispatcher`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18294231)

Comment: Thanks for Tom Aranda's review. I rewrite my content.

Comment: That is a significant improvement. :)

Answer (score 2):

you have to use java swings or awt to show images..have a look at running code http://projectimageprocessing.blogspot.in/2013/05/introduction.html