# Display Keypoints on Image in Android - OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, feature-detection, keypoint

I'm trying display a image with keypoints detected. In my code, i get a list of key points, my i can't display the image on screen. I think that my problem is on converting the image to bitmap from MAT.
What i'm doing wrong ?

Here is my code:

```
    Mat teste = new Mat();
    Mat mRgba = teste.clone();
    Mat outputMat = new Mat();

    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, teste);

    MatOfKeyPoint myKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    FeatureDetector orb = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    orb.detect(teste, myKeyPoints);

    List<KeyPoint> referenceKeypointsList =
            myKeyPoints.toList();


    Imgproc.cvtColor(teste, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB,4);
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(mRgba, myKeyPoints, mRgba, new Scalar(2,254,255), Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, outputMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
    Utils.matToBitmap(outputMat, bitmap);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: BTW: mRgba should be called mRgb since according to your use of cvtColor it contains no alpha channel. And I am not sure what the Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB,4 leads to - maybe remove the 4 since you want a RGB image, i.e. three channels

Comment: The 4 its like Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS.

Comment: The name of variable was a mistake. My result is like a white screen, just it. And i don't understand why , i do like this way: [Follow the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537280/keypoint-list-to-matofkeypoint?rq=1)

Comment: What happens when you leave out the 4 in the cvtColor call?

Comment: the same, if i leave the 4, when i wanna show the key points, my image is full white, i just see a white screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look my code. It works fine

```
int whichDescriptor = siftDescriptor; //freakDescriptor;

        // Features SEARCH
        int detectorType = FeatureDetector.SIFT;
        FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(detectorType);

        Mat mask = new Mat();
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        detector.detect(image, keypoints , mask);               

        if (!detector.empty()){

            // Draw kewpoints
            Mat outputImage = new Mat();
            Scalar color = new Scalar(0, 0, 255); // BGR
            int flags = Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS; // For each keypoint, the circle around keypoint with keypoint size and orientation will be drawn.
            Features2d.drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, outputImage, color , flags); 
            displayImage(Mat2BufferedImage(outputImage), "Feautures_"+detectorType);
        }
```

displayImage() and Mat2BufferedImage() are referenced here
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27163852/3430103)
or [link2](http://answers.opencv.org/question/31505/how-load-and-display-images-with-java-using-opencv/?answer=32292#post-id-32292)