# How to display OpenCV images in Java?

Tags: java, opencv

Sometimes it is necessary to display `OpenCV Mat images` while developing computer vision `Java` applications.
So how can I display these `OpenCV Mat images` in `Java`?

Comment: Have a look also [here](https://github.com/master-atul/ImShow-Java-OpenCV/blob/master/ImShow_JCV/src/com/atul/JavaOpenCV/Imshow.java) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494916/equivalent-method-for-imshow-in-opencv-java-build) and, overall [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/31505/how-load-and-display-images-with-java-using-opencv-solved/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gist with the code I created for this:
https://gist.github.com/fernandoc1/c5105070fa6acf2d0128

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.highgui.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class DisplayImage
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }

    public static BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat m)
    {
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        if (m.channels() > 1)
        {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
        }
        int bufferSize = m.channels()*m.cols()*m.rows();
        byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
        m.get(0, 0, b); // get all the pixels
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(), m.rows(), type);
        final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);  
        return image;
    }

    public static void displayImage(Image img)
    {   
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());        
        frame.setSize(img.getWidth(null)+50, img.getHeight(null)+50);     
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        Mat m = Highgui.imread(args[0]);
        BufferedImage bi = Mat2BufferedImage(m);
        displayImage(bi);
    }
}
```

To compile and run:

```
all:
    javac -cp "/usr/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-248.jar" DisplayImage.java

run:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jni/ java -cp /usr/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-248.jar:. DisplayImage /path/to/image.png
```

It was tested in Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Comment: This code is identical to [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/31505/how-load-and-display-images-with-java-using-opencv-solved/). To avoid it to be considered _plagiarized_ code, please refer to this link in your answer.