# OpenCV java Cant Open the Webcam

Tags: java, opencv

I am learning OpenCV.I am using OpenCV 3.2.0 jar. I am trying to open my  webcam with it but getting an error. here is my Code

Java:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;


public class WebCam {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(0);
    videoCapture.open("the video");
    Mat frame = new Mat();

    while (true){
        videoCapture.read(frame);


    }
}
}
```

The Error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fffbe7d605d, pid=922, tid=0x0000000000000307
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x705d]  objc_msgSend+0x1d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /path /hs_err_pid922.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I have followed a tutorial for python and wrote this code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('THE CAMERA FOR FACE AND EYE',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and it worked .

Please help me out. how can i solve this. on the other hand, i am not finding enough well-explained material online. Please suggest me some good resource.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to open VideoCapture again by using `videocapture.open("the video")` without passing the type of the file. Your code to capture a stream from webcam should just be:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;


public class WebCam {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(0);
Mat frame = new Mat();

while (true){
    videoCapture.read(frame);
    showResult(frame);
}
} 

public static void showResult(Mat img) {
Imgproc.resize(img, img, new Size(640, 480));
MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
Highgui.imencode(".jpg", img, matOfByte);
byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
BufferedImage bufImage = null;
try {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufImage)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

In order to display the frame you need to use the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494916/equivalent-method-for-imshow-in-opencv-java-build) as there is no Java highgui wrapper yet.
I hope this helps.

Comment: This code is turning on the camera but i can't see the view

Comment: Thnak you so much its working, however the stream is not so smooth. but i can work from it. thanks again