# Why does the image break when converted to byte[]? (takePicture with Opencv on Android)

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, android-imageview

I have an project that used Camera and Opencv.
I take picture and crop image with OpenCv. After I have a Mat file to convert Jpeg for send byte[] data to Activity.

Mat to Bitmap

```
bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(checkFrame.cols(),checkFrame.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(checkFrame, bmp2, true);
checkFrame.release();
```

Bitmap to byte[]

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0,stream2);
bmp2.recycle();
bmp2 = null;
byte[] byteArray2 = stream2.toByteArray();
```

On Activity ,

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoView))
                                .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                                        .decodeByteArray(photo2, 0,
                                                photo2.length));
```

But this image is not same with I cropped. This is like 16bit color... 
If I direct send Bitmap to activity and set ImageBitmap, this is good. Why does the image break when it's converted to byte[]?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670933/opencv-java-load-image-to-gui/15702329#15702329) can help