# OpenCV Feature Detection always returns nothing

Tags: java, opencv, feature-detection

**Background:**

I'm working on creating an OpenCV Java command line app to tease out some information from some particle streak images. In particular, I would like to know the dimensions of the smallest possible bounding box which will fit over each particle streak. First I have to find the particles, so I use Simple Blob feature detection.

**Code:**

```
package com.bostonwalker;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfKeyPoint;
import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector;
import org.opencv.features2d.KeyPoint;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java247");

        String sourcePath = "C:\\path_to_image\\05.png";

        Mat srcImgMat = Highgui.imread(sourcePath);

        if (srcImgMat == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to load image at " + sourcePath);
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Loaded image at " + sourcePath);

        MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        FeatureDetector blobDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIMPLEBLOB);
        blobDetector.detect(srcImgMat, matOfKeyPoints);

        System.out.println("Detected " + matOfKeyPoints.size()+ " blobs in the image");

        List<KeyPoint> keyPoints = matOfKeyPoints.toList();

    }
}
```

**Error:**

Unfortunately, the returned matOfKeyPoints is always empty (size always equals 1x0). I have scoured the web, but opencv for desktop Java is not an extremely popular library, and my problem doesn't seem to be that common. I have tried using other feature detector algorithms just to see if I can return any key points whatsoever (the answer is no).

My gut instinct tells me that the color channel scheme of the image is not supported by the Simple Blob algorithm. I have exported the .png files from Photoshop as 8 bits/channel Grayscale and 8 bits/channel RGB Color. It's hard to know what's actually going on in the Highgui.imread() call, and what the Mat data actually looks like.

**Questions:**

1. What is causing the call to detect to return an empty matOfKeyPoints?
2. Is there an easier way to do the image processing I want done?

**More information:**

OpenCV version 2.4.7

Image included below
[image]

**RESOLVED:**

Found the problem. Namely, a small typo in the source path. It looks like Highgui.imread() returns an empty Mat when an incorrect source path is used, instead of returning null like I assumed it would.

Comment: For a start, you can use flags like `Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` in `imread()` to make sure the reading is what you intended (reading directly into grayscale: `Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`). And you can show the images using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15702329/336557. At least you can see what's going on...

Comment: I ran your code on the image and the output was: `Detected 1x3 blobs in the image`. Seems the code works fine...Are you sure you're not getting any errors?

Comment: No errors apparent on my end. Maybe it's related to my Open-CV installation?

Comment: Just to make sure: is the included image the same as the one in the code? (the names are different). The only difference I can see between your code and mine is the library loading: I've added the `OpenCV-247.jar` to my project **libs** and use `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);`.

Comment: I put the jar in my /libs directory and I used Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME, but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried showing the loaded image? Are you sure the input image is not RGB? I think it should be grayscale for the feature detection.