# What is the deference between OpenCV2.4.10 and JavaCV 0.10

Tags: opencv, javacv

I want to know if I download the `OpenCV2.4.10`, is there the need of `JavaCV 0.10` or not, because in the extracted folder of `OpenCV2.4.10` inside `\OpenCV\build\java` there is a Jar file named `opencv-2410.jar`. I am using Java Language to use OpenCV library. But I also saw JavaCV which can be found at http://bytedeco.org website, when I downloaded all Jars, here I also found named opencv.jar file. Now I don't know what is the deference between them, in Java Language which one is better to use. If use `OpenCV2.4.10` is need to `JavaCV 0.10`? and if use `JavaCV 0.10` is need to `OpenCV2.4.10`? or both of them can be independent used? the If anyone know about this please tell me, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you mean "What is the *difference*"? [Deference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deference) means something very different.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV library is written in C/C++. Java wrappers are written so that, C/C++ code could be invoked with JNI. JavaCV( unofficial ) and OpenCV( official ) are completely independent java wrappers to use OpenCV from Java.

I suggest you use OpenCV downloaded from offical [opencv.org](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) website or from OpenCV github repo([1](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv)). Here java wrappers are auto generated during build and so all C/C++ OpenCV functions will have corresponding Java wrappers. This way, every new release or even development versions of OpenCV could be used from Java. This also helps with reading documentation as function parameters matches nearly.

JavaCV is a popular Java wrapper for OpenCV maintained by independent developer(s). It also add helper classes for easier usage. But here, wrappers are not auto generated and so you will need to wait for developers to update to newer versions.

Comment: OK, Thank you for your reply! But I also have a question that is, when I use the OpenCV self wrapper jar file for Java, there are some functions that the jar file dose not have, (i.e cvNameWindow(), cvShowImage() and so on...), and also there is no Java Class for IplImage object ...etc. What do you think about this? Thank you!

Comment: `IplImage` belonged to deprecated C interface of OpenCV and should no more be used. We should now use `Mat`.  `cvNamedWindow`/`cvShowImage` are not exactly image processing algorithms and part of OpenCV highgui module which don't have java wrappers. swing/swt might help. More here http://stackoverflow.com/q/15670933/1180117