# How to loop my webcam stream on java OpenCV

Tags: java, swing, opencv, jframe, opencv3.0

I've been trying to use **OpenCV** (which I'm relatively new to) on **Java** but it seems much more complicated than other languages. While languages like python have *imshow* to loop the webcam, java doesn't have this option.

What I want to do is simply run a file which will load opencv, and use the images it processes in Jframe in order to continuously show updated images (Like a video) from a camera (my webcam).

I can get the code to take a snapshot, but whenever I try to loop more than this I still only get one snapshot.

Here is the code:
`System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

```
    // Instantiating the VideoCapture class (camera:: 0)
    VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);

    // Reading the next video frame from the camera
    Mat matrix = new Mat();

    //Instantiate JFrame 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    //When we find the user close our window.
            frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                    System.out.println("Frame closing...");
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                    capture.release();
                }
            });

    // Instantiating the imgcodecs class
    Imgcodecs imageCodecs = new Imgcodecs();
    // Where we will save the image.
    String file = "C:/Users/Jim/Documents/Samples/sample.jpg";

    // If camera is opened
    if (capture.isOpened()) {
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // While there is next video frame
        while (capture.read(matrix)) {
            System.out.println("Retrieving Frames...");
            capture.read(matrix);

            // Creating BuffredImage from the matrix
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(matrix.width(),
                    matrix.height(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

            //Saving the mat to an image.
            imageCodecs.imwrite(file, matrix);
            imageCodecs.imread(file);

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file); // Inserts the image icon
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon); //Label of ImageIcon

            frame.getContentPane().add(label);
            frame.pack();   
        }
    }`
```

Please help me find what I need to add to have the images update, and also what is unnecessary.

Comment: The first thing you need to understand is, Swing is NOT thread and is single thread, so you need to be careful where you "wait" for content and "where" update the UI from

Comment: My first thought would to try and use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to grab the frames from the Camera and feed those back to the UI via the `publish` and `process` methods. I might also consider using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670933/opencv-java-load-image-to-gui) to convert the image from OpenCV to a `BufferedImage` without needing to read/write, as that's a bottle neck you probably really don't want

Comment: What do you mean by "java doesn't have this option"? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/opencv/highgui/HighGui.html